# why Enum in DependencyProperty returns first value from Enum?

Tags: silverlight, enums, dependency-properties

I had tried to use an Enum in a DependencyProperty but it always takes the first value of the Enum.

e.g.
My Enum :

```
public enum LayoutType
{
     Horizontal,
     Vertical
}
```

Property Declaration :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutTypeProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LayoutType", typeof(LayoutType), typeof(ctrlAllLayouts), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I can access the property in my xaml but problem is that it always give value "Horizontal" if set it is to either "Horizontal" or "Vertical".

Comment: +1 for providing code and a good description

Answer (score 0):

With [Attached Properties](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Attached-Properties-in-Silverlight.aspx) (these are not plain Dependency properties as you used `RegisterAttached`) you must also declare the matching *static* setter and getter methods for it to be parsed. The Xaml parser actually uses those methods.

e.g.

```
public static void SetLayoutType(DependencyObject element, LayoutType value)
{
    element.SetValue(LayoutTypeProperty, value);
}
public static LayoutType GetLayoutType(DependencyObject element)
{
    return (LayoutType)element.GetValue(LayoutTypeProperty);
}
```

If these methods are missing, and because you do not specify a default value in the PropertyMetadata, it will always be set to 0, which is the value of your first enum.